# Displacement Stretched

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, displacement

I have a simple displacement setup as follows:

[image: nodes]

When I apply this same material to two differently sized objects, the displacement seems stretched on the larger object:

[image: screenshot]

Scale has been applied (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).

Is there a way to make the displacement the same 'scale' on objects of any size?

Here is a link to the sample .blend file:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqKxXPZzafVQla8hzonVpxSvpK9jwQ

This was created using Blender 2.8 beta.

Comment: have you applied the scale (ctrl A)?

Comment: @moonboots Yes. I have just updated the question to state that, thanks.

Comment: Try to plug *Object* socket from Texture coordinates to Noise texture

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have consistent scale, create an *Empty* in your scene and make it control the texture scale.

1. Create an Empty
2. Edit your material by adding an *Input>Texture Coordinate*, using the *Object* socket and linking it to the *Empty* in the "*Object*" dropdown

   [image]
3. Scale (, Rotate, Move) the *Empty* to make the feature the size you want. This will apply in a coherent way to both objects that share that material.

[image]

<sup>Big Empty</sup>

[image]

<sup>Small Empty</sup>

Note: if your object is going to be moved in animation, and you want the texture to stick to it, then you should either (1) parent the empty to it, (2) consider following Mark Jackson's answer (although you will need to adjust the proportions of the texture manually), or (3) use an UV map.

Comment: Ingenious! This answer also helped me learn something cool :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use UV textures, then applying materials will try to fit it to the entire object. So if your object is long, then it will stretch to fit your mesh.

To fix this, in your node editor, press "Shift+A" > "Input" > "Texture Coordinate"
                            Press again "Shift+A" > "Vector" > "Mapping"

Connect them up like this and in your Mapping Node, using the Scale to make the noise texture fit to the object. In my case I used the Y axis and increased the Scale of Y by 10.

See below:
[image]

I hope you can see it ok in the image and that this helps you.

Comment: One more thing, without defining the parameters (in this case, the scale) by using a Mapping node, blender will automatically assume the default values (X 1.0, Y 1.0, Z 1.0) and project the texture to fit onto the mesh object which in our case, is not uniform on all sides. So we need a mapping node to tell blender that these values are not default values and it needs to stretch or squash the texture to fit correctly onto our mesh object. In the texture coordinate, using Generated or Object will probably yield similar if not the same result.